# Consumindo um Web Service Asp .Net aplicativo Xamarin

Tags: c#, web-service, xamarin

Estou querendo realizar uma requisição a um Web Service desenvolvido em Asp .Net passando dois parâmetros para meu server. O controller no web Service esta asism:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id1, string id2)
    {
        try
        {
            var destinoDao = new DestinoDAO();

            var destinos = destinoDao.ListaCidadesDestino(id1, id2);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, destinos);
        }
        catch
        {
            var mensagem = "Não foram encontrados destinos com os valores digitados.";

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mensagem);
        }
    }
```

Já o método no Xamarin esta da seguinte maneira:

```
    public async Task GetLista()
    {
        aguarde = true;

            HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();

            var resultado = await cliente.GetStringAsync(urlBuscaDestino + origem + destino);
            var buscaJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuscaJson[]>(resultado);

            foreach (var destino in buscaJson)
            {
                this.ListaDestinos.Add(new Destinos
                {
                    linha = destino.linha,
                    nome = destino.nomeEmpresa,
                    origem = destino.origem,
                    destino = destino.destino,
                    municipio = destino.municipio
                });
            }

        aguarde = false;
    }
```

Observações: as variáveis "origem e destino" estão sendo preenchidas corretamente, a URL também esta correta, quando executo o aplicativo e chego nessa parte ele me da um exception `HttpRequestException`. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
namespace WebServiceAraguaina.Controllers
{
    public class BuscaDestinoController : ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id1, string id2)
        {
            try
            {
                var destinoDao = new DestinoDAO();

                var destinos = destinoDao.ListaCidadesDestino(id1, id2);

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, destinos);
            }
            catch
            {
                var mensagem = "Não foram encontrados destinos com os valores digitados.";

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mensagem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
 public IList<BuscaDestino> ListaCidadesDestino(string origem, string destino)
        {

            var selectCMD = dao.conexao.CreateCommand();
            selectCMD.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT (lin.Cd_Cod_Linha) as Linha, emp.Ds_NomeFantasia AS Empresa, " +
                                    "lin.Ds_Cidade_Origem as Origem, lin.Ds_Cidade_Destino as Destino, " +
                                    "mun.Ds_Municipio as Municipios from Cd_Linha lin left join " +
                                    "Cd_Empresa emp on lin.Cd_Empresa = emp.Cd_Empresa left join " +
                                    "Cd_Paradas par on emp.Cd_Empresa = par.Cd_Empresa left join " +
                                    "Cd_Municipios mun on par.Cd_Cod_Municipio = mun.Cd_Cod_Municipio " +
                                    "where  LTRIM(RTRIM(Ds_Cidade_Origem)) = @Ds_Cidade_Origem and " +
                                    "LTRIM(RTRIM(Ds_Cidade_Destino)) = @Ds_Cidade_Destino";


            var paramOrigem = new SqlParameter("Ds_Cidade_Origem", Convert.ToString(origem));
            selectCMD.Parameters.Add(paramOrigem);

            var paramDestino = new SqlParameter("Ds_Cidade_Destino",Convert.ToString(destino));
            selectCMD.Parameters.Add(paramDestino);

            var ListaDestinos = new List<BuscaDestino>();
            var resultado = selectCMD.ExecuteReader();


            while (resultado.Read())
            {
                var cidadeDestino = new BuscaDestino();
                cidadeDestino.Cod_Linha = Convert.ToString(resultado["Cod_Cod_Linha"]);
                cidadeDestino.Ds_NomeFantasia = Convert.ToString(resultado["Ds_NomeFantasia"]);
                cidadeDestino.Ds_Cidade_Origem = Convert.ToString(resultado["Ds_Cidade_Origem"]);
                cidadeDestino.Ds_Cidade_Destino = Convert.ToString(resultado["Ds_Cidade_Destino"]);
                cidadeDestino.Municipio = Convert.ToString(resultado["Ds_Municipio"]);


                ListaDestinos.Add(cidadeDestino);
            }

            resultado.Close();

            return ListaDestinos;

        }
```

Comment: Poderia colocar a URL que está tentando acessar e o route para seu método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o problema pode ser na forma que está criando seu `HttpClient`.

Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
public async Task GetLista()
{
    try
    {
        aguarde = true;

        HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
        cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.acessoseg.com.br/webservicearaguaina/api/");
        cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string url = $"buscaDestino/{origem}/{destino}";

        var resultado = await cliente.GetStringAsync(url);
        var buscaJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuscaJson[]>(resultado);

        foreach (var destino in buscaJson)
        {
            this.ListaDestinos.Add(new Destinos
            {
                linha = destino.linha,
                nome = destino.nomeEmpresa,
                origem = destino.origem,
                destino = destino.destino,
                municipio = destino.municipio
            });
        }

        aguarde = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exceção gerada
    }
}
```

Note que adicione a propriedade `BaseAddress` e `DefaultRequestHeaders` ao seu objeto `HttpClient`.

Além disso, coloquei dentro de um `try catch` para ajudar a identificar o erro que está acontecendo.

Você pode colocar um `breakpoint` dentro do catch e identificar o que realmente está acontecendo caso o erro persista.

**EDIT**

Após conversar com o Wesley pelo chat de discussão conseguimos identificar o erro e fizemos algumas modificações no `Controller` da `API`.

```
[Route("api/BuscaDestino/{id1}/{id2}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBuscaDestino(string id1, string id2)
{
    try
    {
        var destinoDao = new DestinoDAO();

        var destinos = destinoDao.ListaCidadesDestino(id1, id2);

        return Ok(destinos);
    }
    catch
    {
        var mensagem = "Não foram encontrados destinos com os valores digitados.";

        return Ok(mensagem);
    }
}
```

Feito isso, o método começou a retornar o que era esperado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79028/discussion-between-perozzo-and-q-wesley).

Comment: Ola, desculpa te encomodar novamente, mas voce poderia me dizer como voce fez para testar web service aquela hora?

Comment: Entra no chat ali!

Comment: poderia postar o link novamente, do chat

Comment: tá ai em cima "continuar discussão no chat"